# Magento Session debugging - save/load a session

Tags: magento

I'm debugging a Magento site that has several pages of forms.  A bug appears at the very end of this process.  It's time consuming to re-enter the forms each time I want to test a new iteration.

Is it possible, via core or an extension, to save a session and then reload it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any products or projects which do this specifically, but assuming the form actually stores its values in the PHP session you could probably (i.e. I haven't tested this) throw something together yourself.

When Magento is configured to use file based sessions, you'll find the sessions in the `var/session` folder.  You can read this data into the `$_SESSION` array with the following command line script (assuming a session name of `sess_jd88xxih1f0qp81ar5pkdkc974`)

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('var/session/sess_jd88xxih1f0qp81ar5pkdkc974');
    session_start();
    session_decode($file);
    var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Then, you'd modify the values in `$_SESSION`, and generate a new session string using `session_encode`

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'foo baz bar';
$string = session_encode();
echo $string;
```

And finally, write the session file back out

```
file_put_contents('var/session/sess_jd88xxih1f0qp81ar5pkdkc974', $string);
```

All of that said, look into browser automation tools like Selenium. These tools seems to be the defacto way to solve the sort of problem your'e describing.

Comment: I have an automated system setup, but it's still pretty slow to walk through each page.  I will definitely try this method out next time I'm debugging the session!  

p.s.  Thanks for the great tutorials!